# Line and bitmap collision detection

Tags: javascript, bitmap, collision-detection, p5.js, bresenham

I am trying to implement an efficient collision detection between a line joining two points and a bitmap mask.

**Example:**

[image: bitmap and two points]

Currently I am using [Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to draw each pixel of the line between the two points and comparing that pixel with the bitmap (If the pixel is black return true else continue drawing the line).

```js
collision(x0,y0,x1,y1) {
  let dx = Math.abs(x1 - x0),
    dy = Math.abs(y1 - y0),
    sx = (x0 < x1) ? 1 : -1,
    sy = (y0 < y1) ? 1 : -1,
    err = dx - dy,
    e2

  // loop through line drawing
  while (!((x0 == x1) && (y0 == y1))) {
    e2 = err << 1;
    // check line point x,y against bitmap
    if (bitmap[x0][y0] == 1) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (e2 > -dy) {
      err -= dy;
      x0 += sx;
    }
    if (e2 < dx) {
      err += dx;
      y0 += sy;
    }
  }
  // If looped through whole line and not returned collision return false
  return 0
}
```

Is this a good/efficient approach? Or is there a set method or better approach for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably take this to codereview.stackexchange.com, questions about optimization are meant to be posted there.

Comment: Link to the code review question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195265/line-and-bitmap-collision-detection